# Exclude all tests that end with Test.java in j2objc

Tags: ant, junit4, j2objc, j2objc-gradle

I am struggling to run only tests that end with `*Test.java` and have this in my configs but test runner does not pick anything with this config, am I missing something?

```
testPattern {
    include '**/*Test.java'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working it was not just logging property, it works.